# hidden files are also added with command " git add . "

Tags: git

So in my local repository there are some hidden files (including .gitignore file) and some unhidden files and folders.

I used the command `git add .` and then I run command `git status` . here all files are being under "changes to be committed" part including hidden files.
Please help I am unable to understand how to avoid adding hidden files in git. **Is there a command to not include hidden files?**

FYI: I am using git on the command line

Comment: then dont use `git add .` you generally want .gitignore to be added though. what are you tryign to acheive?

Comment: What do those hidden files do? Add them to `.gitignore` if they are temporary files or your IDE's project files, for example. https://gitignore.io/ can help you write a useful gitignore file so you don't have to manually avoid them. Useful hidden files can be for example `.editorconfig`, `.dockerignore` and should be shared across team members. So it's not always correct to exclude them from commits.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I don't all the files to my cloud form my local repo, and  am trying to understand `git add .` command

Comment: then read the docs and clarify your question. Your question says "git add ." is addign stuff i dont want added.. you never said **what you wanted** or that you were trying to understand **git add .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking don't use `git add .` as an everyday command.  Especially if it's not what you want.  And if you are adding a massive load of files, just follow it with a `git reset <file to not be added>` before your commit.

The only files git won't `add` are the `.git` folder because it knows that is its metadata, and anything not already committed that is listed in a committed `.gitignore` file.

There is no such thing to `git` as a "hidden file".  Technically there is no such thing in Windows, OSX or Linux, there are files that are not normally displayed in UI windows, or by `ls` on the command line, but they are not "hidden" they just match a name pattern that says to not normally display.  `git` doesn't care about any of that and it shouldn't.

And no I don't remember what happens if you have already committed a file and then make it git ignored.

In general I don't use `git add .`  I'm using `git add -u` for all tracked files with changes to be picked up and then using `git reset` on the ones I didn't want added, or `git add -p (optionally with a file name)` for interactive patch adding, or `git add prefix*` to get a group of files.  I only ever generally use `git add .` for a first commit and then I will trim things out of that with `git reset` before committing.  I'm also usually checking status before I even add or commit.

Blindly using `git add .` is a great way to inadvertantly commit test files, password files, diffs, and all sorts of other things that you don't want into the repository.

Answer (score 1):

This will ignore all hidden files in the current directory.

```
git add . ':(exclude).*'
```

But add other files. Also in subdirectories.

But it *will* add hidden files in subdirectories. If you want to ignore
hidden files in the next immediate subdirectory as well:

```
git add . ':(exclude).*' ':(exclude)*/.*'
```

And so on.

(Maybe there is a *pathspec* which will ignore all hiden files
recursively.)

Comment: Hi I have tried this command and I can see that .gitignore is not added this time but still I am able to see hidden files. 
Note that: I have made one txt file hidden from properties menu by right clicking on it.

Comment: If you first do `git restore --staged .` (to unstage all staged files) then this command should do what I described. According to my testing at least.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you don't want to commit certain (hidden) files (e.g. configuration for IDEs, editors, etc.) you want to include those files and directories in the .gitignore file. This way you can use `git add .` again

Comment: Hi As per my understanding, `git add .`  command will add all files except hidden files. But in practical when I run `git add .` all files including hidden files are added.

Comment: @Dare your understanding is wrong